# Is there a way I can grep recursively over all the files in the current directory to find a pattern and then print it in order of high to low?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep, sort

So so far, the code looks like this:

```
grep -rc 'Author' $1
```

It prints out all the files in the directory, which is taken as an argument.
However, how would I sort the output (for example):

```
 - data1:43 
 - data2:56
 - data3:14
```

into a high to low list:

```
 - data2:56
 - data1:43
 - data3:14
```

Comment: Have you tried the `sort` command?

Comment: Yes but it sorts the file name, not the count of how many times Author is in the file

Comment: Sort does more things than you might be aware of, which you can learn more about by reading the man page. Try `sort -t : -k 2,2n`

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -rc 'Author' $1 | sort -t : -k 2,2n
```

is good if you want the number of lines containing the keyword, regardless how many times it repeats on any given line. If you want the actual word count, you should use this

```
echo $1:$(grep -o 'Author' $1|wc -l) | sort -t : -k 2,2n
```

-o option for grep is most probably available on the gnu version of grep. If you are using grep, provided by an older, legacy system, it might not be available. Just a quick heads up.

Answer (score 3):

To sort from highest to lowest:

```
grep -rc 'Author' $1 | sort -r -t ':' -k2,2n
```

- `-r` sorts in reverse order, that is, from highest to lowest.
- `-t` introduces the separator.
- `-k` introduces which fields to sort by. The fields are separated by the separator defined by `-t`. This syntax means to sort by all of the fields between 2 and 2 (so just the second field). The `n` means to use numerical values rather than lexicographic order (so that e.g. `10` goes after `9`, not just after `1`).